# Why am I getting a SIGABRT here?

Tags: sigabrt

I am getting a SIGABRT error here. I don't understand why. Please help me out with this. It runs fine on my computer but on submitting it, it gives a SIGABRT on the very first test case. The memory alloted is to the order of 10^5 only and I have used vectors, instead of arrays, even then it gives this error.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int T;
scanf("%d", &T);
while(T--){
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    int N;
    string str;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    vector <string> f;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        cin>>str;
        f.push_back(str);
    }
    vector<int> op;
    op.resize(10, 0);

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for (int j=0;j <10; j++){
            op[i] *= 2;
            op[i] += ((f[i][j] == '+')? 1: 0);
        }
    }

    int sint=0;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        sint*=2;
        sint += ((s[i] == 'b')? 1: 0);
    }

    int allb = 1023;
    int tgt = allb ^ sint;

    vector <long long int> prev, curr;
    prev.resize(1027, 0);
    curr.resize(1027, 0);   

    prev[op[0]] = 1;
    prev[0] = 1;
    curr[0] = 1;
    curr[op[0]] = 1;
    if (op[0] == 0){
        curr[op[0]]++;
        prev[op[0]]++;
    }

    for (int i=1; i<N; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<=1023; j++){
            curr[j] = (prev[j] + prev[j ^ op[i]])%1000000007;
        }
        for (int j=0; j<=1023; j++)
            prev[j] = curr[j];
    }

    cout<<curr[tgt]<<endl;
}
}
```

Comment: May be you can describe what should your program do. And may be you can spend some effort to add some debugging output or use debugger to investigate where your program gets the signal.

Comment: problem resolved.... thanks